# Rearrangements of infinite products in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers, infinite-product

The Lévy-Steinitz Theorem asserts that for each sequence $(v_i)_{i\geq 1}$ of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the set 
$$S:=S((v_i)_{i\geq 1}):=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} v_{\pi (i)}\in \mathbb{R}^n\:|\: \pi :\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N} \text{ bijective} \right\}$$
 of convergent rearrangements of the corresponding series is either empty or a translate of some subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n $.
In particular, for a sequence $(z_i)_{i\geq 1}$ in $\mathbb{C}$, we have that $S\left((c_i)_{i\geq 1}\right)$ is either empty, a singleton, all of $\mathbb{C}$ or a line in the complex plane.

Now I was wondering if this can be used to make some assertion about the set convergent rearrangements of a product of complex numbers, i.e. about the set $$ P:=P((z_i)_{i\geq 1}):=\left\{\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} v_{\pi (i)}\in \mathbb{C}\:|\: \pi:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N} \text{ bijective} \right\}\text{.}$$

My thoughts:
In $\mathbb{R}$, given a sequence $(c_i)_{i\geq 1}$, we have (if everything is defined) that $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}c_{\pi(i)} = \exp\left(\log\left(\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}c_{\pi(i)}\right)\right)=\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\log(c_{\pi(i)})\right)\text{.}$$

So (by Riemann's Rearrangement Theorem) one obtains $$P\left((c_i)_{i\geq 1}\right)=
\begin{cases}
  \exp(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\log(c_i))    &\text{if } \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\log(c_i) \text{ converges absolutely} \\
  \mathbb{R}^+_0 \text{ or } \mathbb{R}^-_0  &\text{if }\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\log(c_i) \text{ is conditionally convergent}\\
  \emptyset   &\text{else}\\
\end{cases}$$

Logarithmising in $\mathbb{C}$ and considering the case where $S(\log(z_i)_{i\geq 1}))$ is a line, say $S=\{a+tb:t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$, we would get that $P((z_i)_{i\geq 1}))=\{\exp(a+tb):t\in \mathbb{R}\}$, which describes a spiral  in $\mathbb{C}$.

However in $\mathbb{C}$, the logarithm is only unique up to integer multiples of $2\pi i$, so this approach seems rather useless to me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logarithm is fixed one for all. Also $c_j \to 1$ (otherwise the product never converges whatever is the rearrangement) and you'll choose any value of $\log c_j$ such that $\log c_j\to 0$.

Thus the ambiguity is a $2i\pi k_j$ term for finitely many $\log c_j$ which won't change the image by $\exp$ of the obtained subset of $\Bbb{C}\cup-\infty$.

The set you'll obtain will be : either a point, a spiral $e^{a+bt},t\in \Bbb{R}\cup \infty$ for some $ \Re(b)< 0$, a circle $e^{a+it}$, empty, or the whole of $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: ...or a ray $e^{a+t}$.

Comment: it's a case of spiral, I separated the circle because it is $t\in [0,2\pi]$ and it doesn't have $0$

Comment: Thanks! 
Just to sum up and see if I understand you correctly, you first ignore the finitely many $c_j$ where the ambiguity occurs, then logarithmise the remaining product, apply the theorem to get a line in $\mathbb{C}$ and apply the exponential function, which gives a spiral (or circle/ray). 

Now multiplying by the finite product we ignored in the beginning again results in a spiral (resp. circle/ray), which is then the set $P((c_i)_{i\geq 1})$ we were looking for. Is that your argument?

Comment: Yes, if $a_n-b_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n$ then $S(a_n) = S(b_n)+\sum_n (a_n-b_n)$, when $a_n-b_n=2i\pi k_n $ it means $\exp(S(a_n))=\exp(S(b_n))$. @user631620